# `start .` stopped to work from within FAR manager

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, far-manager

I was always using

```
start .
```

command to open current directory in Windows Explorer from within FAR manager. Now it stopped to work and displays application selection window "How do you want to open this file" instead of working.

Command still works from withing CMD window.

Comment: As a replacement for `start .` you could execute the command `.`.
Does `start .` work if you start a CMD instance within Far Manager? 
Do you start FAR Manager directly or use it with ConEmu maybe? 
What is XXX in `Always use this app to open XXX files?` in your message?
`start` is an internal `CMD` command and I don't think FAR Manager is doing anything special. I would check 1) if there is another CMD in the path, 2) if the problem happens only for your user, 3) if the problem persists if you create a new FAR installation.

Comment: Which version? `start .` works for me in 3.0.5000 and 3.0.5200 (both x64) under Win 10.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this command in an interactive way (rather than as part of a script), you could consider alternative methods, which might prove more convenient for you.

#### Method 1: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Place your cursor at the `..` entry:

[image: cursor at ..]

and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. A Windows Explorer window for the current directory will open immediately.

If the current directory is a root directory, then bring forward the Change Drive menu (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, depending on which panel is active):

[image: Change Drive menu]

and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

<sub>Note that you can use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> shortcut on any highlighted directory name as well. More generally, this combination just calls the default application for the active panel's highlighted entry. For directories the default happens to be Windows Explorer. And the `..` entry in this specific case is treated as a reference to the *current* directory.</sub>

#### Method 2: User Menu option

My personal choice lately: an option in the User Menu. In my menu it is always the first option, for the most convenience, because that way you just press <kbd>F2</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I define the option thus:

[image: Menu option]

For reference, the text of the command is this:

```
explorer.exe /select,"!\!.!"
```

This command will not just invoke the Windows Explorer for the current directory but the active panel's highlighted file will also be highlighted in the opened window.

It should be noted, though, that this method only works well if you only ever use a global User Menu